# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Congratulations, RPG! As a perk of graduating, you get Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Users of the community will provide images and content links, and then community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool server utilities
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1497).

Comment: Y'all can check out [AskUbuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2158/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)'s ads, for examples of how to use this. :)

Comment: Would open source projects of interest be ok?

Comment: @C.Ross anything community-relevant should be okay.

Comment: I imagine that an Obsidian Portal Ad would make some sense

Comment: @SimonWithers I passed along your suggestion to Brett; he said he'd reach out to the company for some creative. :)

Comment: What kind of sites makes sense for us to point to? Software to help run RPGs? Actual games? Other communities?

Comment: @SimonWithers Not to be unkind, but that's kind of up to y'all. :)

Answer (score 21):

[image: Find out the odds]

Comment: The only problem with it is that it reports in %, rather than in X/N fractions... and hides some of the granularity because of it. Definitely a great resource to promote.

Answer (score 19):

[image: RPG.SE Twitter]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Roll20 - Virtual tabletop gaming that tells a story]

Comment: Roll20 is a Kickstarter funded, free, browserbased virtual Tabletop that is in very active developpment, and works pretty good for a variety of RPG styles...

Answer (score 12):

[image: Free app for Role-Playing via Hangouts]

Comment: This is an excellent battlemap/dice roller application for hangouts. We've been using it for several weeks to facilitate Brian's weekly game and are for the most part very pleased with it.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Community Promotion Ads - 2012]

Comment: I have to say, I like the superuser version much, much more. I look at this and I think "Huh? Whatever. Why do I care.", The SU ad tells me why I should care, or not.

Comment: I like the *idea* but I just don't think the image is in line with the quality of the site.

Comment: I'll try to come up with something more appropriate then. Maybe spend 12 or even *15* seconds on the new one.

Comment: Updated the image. I'm no artist so I just stole the meta dragon. Comments/criticism welcome.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Looks good.  Happy to be the one to push it to +6.

Answer (score 7):

[image: PCGen - The Ennie Award Winning RPG Character Generator]

Comment: PCGen is a great character creation tool, and I'd love to get them some more attention.  Also looking for Java developers to contribute if you're into that sort of thing!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Edgerunner, a different interpretation of FATE for a dark future]

Comment: As long as you put the site in your credits :-).

Comment: Will the main page introduction suffice :)

Comment: That will do...

Answer (score 5):

[image: The Tangled Web]

Comment: The blocky font used for the ad copy makes me cringe.

Comment: I'll talk to the TTW and see if I can get a better image, then ;-)

Comment: Any movement there?

Comment: I asked for it, but haven't heard back.