# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful resources for both the GM and the player
- utilities for running meets online
- the site's twitter account
- cool roleplaying events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2723).

Comment: I've copied over all the 2012 ads that had been voted 6+. Apparently this means I can't vote on any of them… Ah well, one for the team!

Comment: So anyone can just make up an ad?

Comment: @okeefe Yep! All you really need is community approval for the ad, and then it'll be in rotation.

Comment: I still think we need to put together an ad for sci-fi...

Comment: @C.Ross There are two already here: the TARDIS and the Deathstar ones go to scifi.SE. I *personally* think they need more explicit site branding on them – but, well, that's what the voting is for!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No, I think we should be putting an ad for RPG on scifi.SE, since they do have two!

Answer (score 27):

[image: Find out the odds]

Comment: I'm months late and someone has probably already mentioned this somewhere, but AnyDice gave us a shout-out on his [blog](http://catlikecoding.com/blog/tags:anydice), thanking us for promoting his site.

Comment: Nice ad design, but the JPEG compression artifacts are pretty bad (especially for a PNG image!).  I made [a somewhat cleaner version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b3WQX.png) of the ad; if you think it's OK, feel free to use it. (I also redid the text a bit -- I feel it's better, but you might legitimately disagree.) It would be even better, though, if we could find a proper high-res / vector version of the logo somewhere (like, say, by asking the owner of the site).

Answer (score 18):

[image: Roll20 - Virtual tabletop gaming that tells a story]

Answer (score 16):

[image: RPG.SE Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Community Promotion Ads - 2013]

Answer (score 10):

[image: SciFi & Fantasy]

Comment: I saw this and hoped for a Star Wars RPG thing... I'd prefer to see something indicating that this is an ad for the scifi stack exchange in the ad copy

Comment: I think it's fine. Ads are made to make people click; some false positives are expected.

Answer (score 9):

[image: PCGen - The Ennie Award Winning RPG Character Generator]

Comment: Thanks for the help SevenSidedDie!

Answer (score 8):

[image: Edgerunner, a different interpretation of Fate for a dark future]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: @JNat Please make a new post with the new ad instead of changing an existing one. The votes are for the existing ad and can't be "given" to a new ad by one person. If this ad is obsolete and not wanted by the A&M.SE anymore, then leave a comment saying so instead and it can be deleted. Either way, please do post the new ad for consideration and voting.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I made a new post with another ad. Note that this one is *not* obsolete. :)

Comment: @JNat Awesome, excellent. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: We had decided to do that changing thing because we have other 2 ads (besides the ones posted here already), and we thought it was better to change one instead of having here four different posts advertising for the same site. But if you find it better like this, we see no problem at all. :)

Answer (score 6):

[image: SciFi & Fantasy]

Comment: I saw this and hoped for a Dr Who RPG thing... I'd prefer to see something indicating that this is an ad for the scifi stack exchange in the ad copy

Comment: agree with simon, needs to declare it's a link to scifi

Answer (score 5):

[image: I am Jack's neural implant]

Answer (score 5):

[image: DerekDice is a flexible online die roller]

Comment: Typing `fudge`, `"fudge"`, `monopoly`, or `"monopoly"` does nothing.

Comment: Thank you for telling me! It is fixed now, as I broke it when I added validation. Oh, and by the way @SevenSidedDie DerekDice can roll seven sided dice. You could roll 10,000 if you wanted to ;D. Try "10000d7" without the quotes :D

Comment: 404 Not found - what gives?

Comment: Sorry, I moved to howderek.com. Updating.... @YianestheSneak

Answer (score 4):

[image: Anime and Manga SE]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Anime & Manga SE Community on FB]

Comment: -1 I think the main anime site link, but links to another site's secondary pages (like Facebook/Google-Plus) seem weird -- especially when they say "like us" or "+1 us".

Answer (score 1):

[image: Anime & Manga SE Community on G+]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Free app for Role-Playing via Hangouts]

**Edited to add:** [This project is being cancelled](https://plus.google.com/110771920494591644897/posts/jAUswUixcHr); we should probably yank the advertisement.