# Multiple Community ads for the same project

Tags: discussion, advertising

I just saw that there are two different ads for scifi.se at the [Community Promotion Ads 2013](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/community-promotion-ads-2013) question. Does that mean it is ok to post more than one ad for a single project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes.**  People are welcome to vote for both or neither.  Only the ads the community approves will be put in rotation.  However, you shouldn't post the *same* ad twice.

Comment: I take this as the definitive answer, thanks :)