# Mouseover text for community promotion ad says 2012

Tags: support, status-completed, advertising

The advert for Community promotion ad says 2012 in its mouseover text, but the graphic links you to a 2013 site.

Blah blah attention to detail yada yada?

Obligatory:

[image]

Comment: Well spotted :o)

Answer (score 1):

I beleive it was copy and paste error on [this post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2728/45).  I edited, it and the system should pick that up shortly.