# Which metas should we draw more attention to by featuring?

Tags: discussion, meta

Meta is the part of the site where we figure out what's going on with the other, "main" part of the site. From an individual question's closure to electing a new moderator to figuring out how to help homebrewers ask about their creations, a lot goes on here.

Roughly 0.3% of mainsite users come here and access meta. While I think we've got great discussion discussion here and thank so many of you for chiming in on topics varying from minute to strongly-felt, I'd love to see even more people *aware of* meta, its role, its content, and the policies on it that govern our day-to-day work on mainsite.

We can bring more attention to a meta post by making it [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) which places it in the community sidebar. Only an elected moderator can add this tag, but we're interested in finding metas we should draw more attention to by featuring them. This would be a rotating scheme where we feature 1-2 metas periodically to draw more attention to them and help people learn about how our site works.

### Which metas should we feature this way?

We need your assistance working out which metas we should draw attention to periodically.

If there's a meta you think should be featured below add it as a new answer here. One meta per answer. Please include a short pitch as to why you think this meta is a good way to draw a stackizen to meta for the first time.

As a voter reviewing submissions by others:

- Vote up if you think this would be a good meta to rotate through the "featured" sidebar.
- Ignore ones you don't want to see.
- Save downvotes for when you think a post would actually be *bad* for a mainsite user's first interaction with meta. (And please comment explaining your downvote.)

There's no magic number right now, we're making this up as we go along.

Thank you!

<sub>Format and content of this post shamelessly cribbed from [RPG General Chat: vote for your feeds!](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3041/23970)</sub>

Comment: I gave this a significant rewrite around the middle to more clearly convey what we're doing here and why. The original read like a poll on how moderators should use the featured tag at all.

Comment: Perfect--thank you.

Comment: Should this be… featured? :3

Comment: I was actually just thinking about that... an answer that has its own question as the "answer." Will it crash the servers? Should we loop in [Nick Craver](https://nickcraver.com/)?

Answer (score 9):

[FAQ Index for RPGSE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7064/23970)

We have an FAQ! It's full of questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)! It links to a couple-dozen excellent metas that cover a lot of situations users ask questions about!

Comment: I down voted this because I think certain things are so important (Like this) that they need to be MORE prominent. I don't know if that is possible, but having a permanent FAQ on a weekly cycle doesn't work for me.

Comment: @SeriousBri thanks for the input. To make sure I'm hearing you correctly, are you saying you think the FAQ should *always* be featured, or *never* be featured, or something I'm not seeing?

Comment: I think it needs to be in front of people 24/7, not on a list that constantly changes (As is the stated intent in the question). So if featuring is the most visible it can be then yes feature it, but I don't think that goes far enough.

Answer (score 4):

**None of them.**

We have a [faq](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) and that's what's needed. Old metas, unlike old main site questions, are often just old and it's OK to open a new question instead of chiming in somewhere in the years-old soup of some previous one. Replaying them serves what purpose? And it distracts from actual timely new metas being featured.

Doing this is a) additional work, b) open to people gaming the system when some factional war breaks out, c) adds no value.  Don't do it.

Comment: Maybe just the FAQ index itself needs to be occasionally [featured].

Comment: Or permanently, if it’s hard to find for new people, but then the rest should all be timely.

Comment: I'd be game for sometimes featuring the FAQ, but otherwise reserving featured for timely things.

Answer (score 2):

[How is the community doing? [2018]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7925/23970)

Annually we post a meta asking broadly for feedback on the site and suggestions for improvement; here is the most recent of those.

Answer (score 2):

[What are RPG.SE's goals for Hot Network Questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8521/23196)

Topical, relevant, and it seems like no-one cares about it here. If anyone *does* care, they should be given the incentive to voice their opinion.