# TRPG General Chat: vote for your feeds! (2e: Electric Bugaloobear)

Tags: discussion, chat, feed

## Chat? Feeds?

SE sites have associated chat rooms. This site's main one is [TRPG General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11/). Check it out!

SE chat supports [RSS feeds](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-an-rss-feed-4684568), which shows up as little ticker pop-ups from time to time.

For the last seven years [this meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3041/4398) has been the place to decide what goes in our ticker feed (click [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11?tab=feeds) for current feed list), but it's getting cluttered with outdated material and the years-old voting no longer reflects the modern chat's constituency. So I'm starting over with this post!

## Vote for feeds!

Pretty straightforward procedure, really. Each "answer" post is suggesting one feed to add to the chat ticker.

- Click on the links to see what content the feeds will be posting to the site.
- **Vote up feeds you personally want to see.**
- Just ignore the ones you don't want to see.
- Save downvotes for when you think something is actively detrimental rather than just irrelevant to your interests. (Please consider leaving an explanatory comment if you do this.)

(If you don't ever plan to participate in the TRPG General Chat, please think about whether your vote is useful.)

This is meant to be a less-formal variant of the [community ads procedure](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/community-promotion-ads-2013). Note that moderators/room owners will have to go in and make the changes by hand. There is no magic vote number for a feed to automagically get into the ticker (I reserve the right to veto feeds with bigotry, for example) but feeds run by rpg.se chat-users are likely to get in faster and with fewer votes: we want to encourage each others' projects!

## Suggest feeds!

If you think there's a feed that should show up in general chat, add it as a new answer here, with one feed per answer.

**Feed suggestions should be pitches telling us why we'd like the feed in our ticker,** providing useful information like general focus, update frequency (feeds which update many times a day are not popular with the chat), and representative examples of posts.

Please include a link to both the feed's readable page *and* RSS page, if they're different; your feed is less likely to get voted for if you only link to the RSS code page, and less likely to get put in the ticker if the room owners have to go digging through the site for the RSS link.

---

08 May 2020: I've pruned the existing feed list back significantly (mostly chopping dead wood and feeds whose content has become less acceptable over time) and I'm pulling the remaining feeds' pitches over from the old thread. If they don't get votes I'm probably gonna remove them too.

Comment: Is it worth listing somewhere in the post what the current feeds are, for posterity? (Even if not, I think it should probably be made more obvious that the current feeds are listed in the second page linked in your post: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11?tab=feeds)

Comment: @V2Blast Edited to be quite clear about where to find the current feeds.

Comment: Thanks! Also, it seems implied by the post, but is this specifically for nominating feeds to appear in the top-left ticker - and not to appear inline as messages? (I ask because the RPG.SE Hot Network Questions feed is currently already appearing as the latter (inline messages), but you've left an answer linking that feed, so I'm not sure whether it's proposing that that inline feed be changed to a ticker, or maintaining the status quo, or something else.)

Comment: Yeah. I'd prefer to keep stuff in the ticker unless there's a clear exception justifying main-chat bot use; this is rare enough that people can address it with comments (like linksassin is doing) but I'm not going to call attention to the option by including it in the main-post instructions.

Answer (score 11):

### RPG.SE Hot Network Questions

Site: [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), but only the [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions) ones.

Feed link: https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/rpg.stackexchange.com

Does what it says on the tin. We often get between four and seven Hot Network Questions a day, sometimes a little more or less. This feed pushes those questions onto our ticker when they get hot. It's good to have a lot of eyes on questions with a significant amount of new-user traffic.

Comment: I like this one as an in chat feed so that it is searchable. For me it is by far the most useful feed.

Comment: Probably relevant for historical context: [Can we add the feed of RPG.se Hot Network Questions to the chat feed?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8925)

Comment: I'm definitely with Link on this one, I normally like the ticker feeds but for HNQs I definitely think the current direct-to-chat method is the way to go. I often miss things in the ticker feed but the hot questions seem right to be in the chat.

Answer (score 10):

### New RPG.SE Questions

Site: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest

Feed link: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/feeds

Populates the ticker with the newest questions being asked on our own Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 8):

### Beyond the Bundle

site: http://beyondthebundle.com/

feed link: http://beyondthebundle.com/feed/

The Bundle of Holding is a tabletop RPG version of the videogame Humble Bundle: it promotes small-business RPGs by offering cheap bundle rates for high-quality indie games, and donating proceeds to charities of the creators' choice. Beyond the Bundle is their blog. Mostly posts when bundles change, no more than once a week.

Answer (score 6):

### Fantastic Maps (blog)

site: http://www.fantasticmaps.com/

feed link: http://www.fantasticmaps.com/feed/

Fantastic Maps is a down-to-earth blog about mapmaking, with a strong fantasy bent. It talks about the mechanics, philosophies, and practices of making fictional maps. Posting is extremely infrequent, but when they post the content is consistently engaging and useful.

Comment: "Extremely infrequent" is right... It looks like their last post was on April 12, 2020, but the post before that one is from April 30, 2017, and May 23, 2016 is the next most recent one before that.

Comment: @V2Blast I was ready to burn this one out of the ticker, and then there was a sign of life! Its content is historically so good that I'm willing to wait a while and see.

Comment: As of November 2021, their last update is still April 12, 2020. But no harm in keeping the feed present.

Answer (score 3):

### Ars Ludi/Lame Mage (blog)

site: http://arsludi.lamemage.com/

feed link: http://arsludi.lamemage.com/index.php/feed/

Ars Ludi/Lame Mage was described in [the original feed curation thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3177/4398):

> Is an intelligent, well-written blog about RPGs by Microscope creator Ben Robbins. He writes about various experiments he tried, social issues with RPGs, and actual play from the games he's written.

Posts about twice a month.

Comment: It's also where I saw the [West Marches](http://arsludi.lamemage.com/index.php/78/grand-experiments-west-marches/) format first described :)

Answer (score 2):

### The Walking Mind

site: http://walkingmind.evilhat.com/

feed link: http://walkingmind.evilhat.com/feed/

As described in [the original feed curation thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3134/4398):

> "The Walking Mind is Rob Donoghue, co-founder of Evil Hat and erratic RPG writer." A fairly active blog. The author has recently concluded a very in-depth look at 13th Age and Numenera. Well-written, thought-out, and a game designer's perspective is a plus, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

### Sly Flourish (blog)

site: http://slyflourish.com/

feed link: https://slyflourish.com/index.xml

As described in [the original feed curation thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3135/4398):

> Sly Flourish has started as a D&D 4e blog (hence the name, I'm guessing), but has since moved on to broader topics. Weekly posts, focuses on practical advice.

Answer (score 1):

### James Mendez Hodes (blog)

site: https://jamesmendezhodes.com/

feed link: https://jamesmendezhodes.com/?format=rss

The blog of James Mendez Hodes is a rich resource of information and guidance on making and playing games audaciously while being safe, informed, and considerate. He posts a usually-lengthy entry every couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

### Ponderings on Games (blog)

site: http://ponderingsongames.com/

feed link: http://ponderingsongames.com/feed/

RPG.SE user [Magician](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1421/magician)'s blog, which [they described](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3058/4398):

> My own blog, Ponderings on Games. Was primarily about D&D 4e, now moved on to other games. Low volume, vaguely game design perspective.

Posts rarely and erratically.

Comment: Seems they were posting reasonably regularly on the blog back in 2018, up until November... But their only post since then was once in July 2019. (The user themselves last visited RPG.SE in January, it seems.)

Comment: @V2Blast For Stack-user-associated feeds I'm inclined to be *extremely* generous about letting them sit around in the feed inactive. An inactive feed doesn't actually cause a visible problem in the ticker, after all.

Comment: Oh sure, I wasn't saying "this feed should definitely be removed", just observing the dropoff in activity. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Siskoid's Blog of Geekery (blog; RPG tag only)

site: http://siskoid.blogspot.com/search/label/RPGs

feed link: http://siskoid.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/RPGs

Originally described in [the previous feed meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3059/4398):

> Siskoid's Blog of Geekery has an enjoyable RPG tag. For example, in addition to more traditional RPG experience/commentary/review posts, he does the really quite cool [Seasons of *Doctor Who: Adventures in Time and Space*](http://siskoid.blogspot.com/search/label/Seasons%20of%20DWAITAS): as part of his "watching and reviewing all of *Doctor Who* in order, he re-casts each season as an RPG campaign, providing character sheets and summaries of the fictional play.

Answer (score 1):

### Deeper in the Game: From Geekdom to Freedom (blog)

site: http://bankuei.wordpress.com/

feed link: http://bankuei.wordpress.com/feed/

Described in [the original feed curation thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3049/4398):

> This blog is low-volume (I consider that a plus). It includes indie-games content, D&D content, theory and tools (like the "Same Page Tool" that we cite constantly in comments and chat), and content about social-justice issues in fiction and roleplaying.

Posts rarely.

Answer (score 1):

### The RPG Pipeline (announcement blog)

site: https://theindierpgpipeline.blogspot.com/

feed link: http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheIndieRpgPipeline

Posts often, because RPG creators are hopping!

> The RPG Pipeline is a posting board to keep track of upcoming tabletop rpgs. When I see a new rpg released, going into crowdfunding or looking for playtesters, I post it here. I cover only games (not supplements or other add-ons) and only English language.

Answer (score -5):

## The Angry GM

site: https://theangrygm.com/

Feed link: https://theangrygm.com/feed/

As described from the [site](https://theangrygm.com/about/), because I'm terrible at writing.

> The Angry GM provides RPG Advice with Attitude. Whether you call yourself a Dungeon Master, a Game Master, a Storyteller, a Keeper, Game Trustee, or Lord of the Game, and whatever your experience level, The Angry GM is pretty much the best damned resource for table-top role-playing game advice. As long as you don’t mind getting yelled at. See, The Angry GM doesn’t f$&% around. He’ll tell it like it is. And he doesn’t take a lot of crap. But whether you play D&D, Pathfinder, Savage Worlds, Dungeon World, OSR, or any other motherf$&%ing RPG ever, The Angry GM can help you run less worse games.

Comment: Angry GM was removed from our feeds and will not be coming back unless/until the author makes amends for blatantly racist rhetoric. TRPG General Chat doesn't want that in our feeds.